# Could .so file be linked to executable statically?

Tags: linker, elf

Since object file (ET_REL, *.o) must have sections, and dynamic libraries (ET_DYN, *.so) have both segments and sections, could the *so files be linked statically, even if it is aimed for dynamic linking?

Answer (score 1):

> dynamic libraries (ET_DYN, *.so) have both segments and sections

Dynamic libraries *usually* have sections, but only because they haven't been stripped. There are plenty of dynamic libraries that do *not* have any sections (only segments are *required* for the library to work).

> could the *so files be linked statically, even if it is aimed for dynamic linking?

No. Most UNIX linkers consider `a.out` and `foo.so` to be *final* link products, with no provision for any further modification.

Including `foo.so` into `a.out` is theoretically possible, but quite hard in practice.

Consider a case where `foo.so` defines and exports functions `foo` and `bar`, and that `foo` calls `bar`. Suppose it were possible to link `foo.so` into `a.out` which had a different definition of `bar`.

What should happen in this case? A multiple definition error? `foo` call `bar` inside `foo.so`? `foo` call `bar` inside `a.out`? Something else? All of the above alternatives would require linker to become much more complicated than it is now, and it's complicated enough already.